# What areas of C++ are most useful to a C programmer?

Tags: c++, c

I don't like C++, I like C, but I found I have to know something about C++ just like STL etc., to do some C-like C++.

What should I know about C++ at least? (language specification, API, libs etc.)

Comment: CPP is short for C PreProcessor, what you probably mean is C++.

Comment: Don't hate any language ! There isn't enough love in the world, and you waste your time hating (: ?

Comment: Hate leads to better languages and sudden paradigm shifts.

Comment: `C-like C++` is having the worst of both worlds, IMHO

Comment: *Why* are you writing C-like C++?  Write C if that's what you want to write.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Hate towards C++ and love to C does not look as the best candidate to produce a paradigm shift... unless you want to reinvent Objective-C...

Comment: I'm thinking more like @dribeas: Your assumption that the Obj-C/C++ direction are the next step I believe to be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I don't agree with your sentence. People who writes C++ code knowing only C are writing in *C with classes*, and what they usually do is taking advantage of overloading and class/struct member functions.

This, in my opinion, is a bad style, it doesn't use C++ at is best, and in general there's no point in writing code that way. Using some C++ libraries (like, but not only, STL) doesn't improve the situation. You'll be able to find a C library providing any data structure and algorithm provided by STL.

What you need to write C++ is to change your mind, to learn new programming paradigms. C++ is not C with classes, otherwise you're just using marginal features (like function overloading and member functions - which can be easily simulated in C) exchanging that with many issues (like symbol mangling, slow compilation time etc).

Comment: Yes, in the immortal words of a little green muppet (no, not Kermit the frog): do, or do not. There is no try.

Comment: Of particular interest: RAII (or much better named SBRM).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html

Good read for your question

Comment: Better read and without an annoying registration popup: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#C

Answer (score 1):

You should learn Object-oriented programming concepts. It helps you to reuse source code and is easier to do maintenance and fix bugs. Object-oriented programming is very important if you want to develop a large project.

From C++, you should learn:

- classes and objects: it helps you to abstract what you want to represent.
- inheritance and virtual functions: Object-oriented programming features.
- exceptions: it helps you to find and handle errors.
- templates: you can write classes and functions for any data type.
- stl containers: linked list, binary tree,

Answer (score 0):

You can write c code and it will compile fine on a cpp compiler. Some things like enums and voids are a bit different, but other than that, anything you write in c will compile in cpp too.

Comment: Really? What about the snippet: `int class;` ? :-)

Comment: There are much better examples of valid C which is invalid C++ than using new keywords like 'class', 'template', etc.